# mockito when interact with each other in different method

Tags: java, spring, mockito

I have a short piece of code and two unit test. Strangely when I launch the test separately they works well but when I launch them together it look like the second method use the "when" of the first method.

Tested method :

```
public ProductIssuer update(ProductIssuer productIssuer) {
    findById(productIssuer.getId())
            .orElseThrow(() -> new B4FinanceException(ErrorCode.USER_NOT_FOUND, "Please provide an existing user"));

    return productIssuerRepository.save(productIssuer);
}
```

The tests :

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;

public class ProductIssuerServiceTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private static ProductIssuerService productIssuerService;

    @Mock
    private static ProductIssuerRepository productIssuerRepository;

    public static final UUID DEFAULT_UUID = UUID.fromString("b8fc499a-2084-11e8-b467-0ed5f89f0000");
    private static final String DEFAULT_NAME = "productIssuer Name";

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void updateNotFoundThrowException() {
        ProductIssuer productIssuer = new ProductIssuer();

        productIssuer.setName(DEFAULT_NAME);

        when(productIssuerRepository.findById(any())).thenReturn(Optional.empty());

        assertThatExceptionOfType(B4FinanceException.class).isThrownBy(() -> productIssuerService.update(productIssuer));
    }

    @Test
    public void update() {
        ProductIssuer productIssuer = new ProductIssuer();

        productIssuer.setName(DEFAULT_NAME);
        productIssuer.setId(DEFAULT_UUID);

        when(productIssuerRepository.findById(any())).thenReturn(Optional.of(productIssuer));
        when(productIssuerRepository.save(any())).thenReturn(productIssuer);

        productIssuerService.update(productIssuer);
    }
}
```

The result is ok for the first test (updateNotFoundThrowException) but for the second test I got a "Please provide an existing user" error.

Comment: Why do you declare `ProductIssuerService` and `ProductIssuerRepository` as `static`? Make them non-static and you should see expected behavior.

Comment: What a stupid mistake ... Didn't thought about that. I needed them as static for a previous implementation and copy past got me.